# How to kill session in jQuery function when I redirect to the logout page through jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi all,
I have gone through this example to end session when user was inactive for some amount of time which works fine

http://www.philpalmieri.com/js_sandbox/timedLogout/

But when it redirects back to `logout` page and if I access the page with sessions I am able to see the page access with the data. I don't want this to be done. When user logged out on inactive session through the `jQuery` function I would like to kill the session which I am having too? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `logout_url` option for that purpose. Create generic http handler in your project and use it for performing logout on server:

Hahdler's code:

```
public class LogoutHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Session.Abandon();
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

markup:

```
$(function () {
     $(document).idleTimeout({
          inactivity: 30000,
          noconfirm: 10000,
          sessionAlive: 10000,
          logout_url: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/LogoutHandler.ashx") %>',
          redirect_url: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/LogoutHandler.ashx") %>' // suggested by Ramakrishna
     });
});
```

Comment: Should i call this process request in my application?

Comment: @Ramakrishna no, you shouldn't

Comment: But this didn't work for me.. I just wrote as per you said but in the script i called as follows `logout_url: 'LogoutHandler.ashx',` is it ok or should i call as per you written

Comment: Even though i wrote as per you given it didn't work for me.. Still i am able to view the page

Comment: You may write `'LogoutHandler.ashx'` till handler located at the same level as you page where you use idleTimeout. I'm forgot that for access to Session your handler must be marked with `IRequiresSessionState` interface. Check updated answer

Comment: still the same issue will there be a problem as i am using form authentication

Comment: Set brackpoint in `ProcessRequest` method and check that it called before redirection onto login page

Comment: How you are create that handler? Did you choose a **Generic Handler** in the `Add New Item` dialog or ASP.NET Handler?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5234/discussion-between-yuriy-rozhovetskiy-and-ramakrishna)

Comment: Hi this works fine the only problem is initially i set some page on `redirect_url` so this always take the default one which i initially taken . So i take a new copy and test it with `redirect_url: 'Handler.ashx'` then it works perfectly as per my requirement. Thanks for your help..

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I've update answer with your workaround.